# Tensorflow GPU: Failed to create cuSolverDN instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Tensorflow 14 + cuda 8.0 + cudnn6.0 + gcc4.8, training progress:

*2018-08-01 15:48:53.786570: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Device peer to peer matrix
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786874: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1051] DMA: 0 1 2 3 
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786881: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1061] 0:   Y Y Y Y 
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786884: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1061] 1:   Y Y Y Y 
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786887: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1061] 2:   Y Y Y Y 
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786890: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1061] 3:   Y Y Y Y 
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786897: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:17:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786901: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:18:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786905: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:2) -> (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-08-01 15:48:53.786908: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:3) -> (device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:b3:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)*

number of trainable parameters: 40564970

num_total_steps:  543300

*2018-08-01 15:51:36.092723: I tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.cc:159] Creating CudaSolver handles for stream 0xcd4b5330
2018-08-01 15:51:36.144979: F tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.cc:94] Check failed: cusolverDnCreate(&cusolver_dn_handle) == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS Failed to create cuSolverDN instance*.

I cannot find anybody having this problem. But it cuts down my training progress. Please, can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for the late respone. Could you try again using these code lines - `config = tf.ConfigProto()` 
`config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` to fix this error. Also, Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66370376/14290681) similar resolved issue for your reference.