# TensorFlow crashes with Failed to create cuSolverDN instance when tf.linalg.inv is called

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running the `tensorflow/tensoflow:latest-gpu` docker container. I can run simple vector operations like `@` for matrix multiplication without a problem. However, when I run the following minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.linalg.inv(tf.eye(10))
```

I get the following error:

```
2021-02-15 16:18:20.375254: I tensorflow/core/util/cuda_solvers.cc:180] Creating CudaSolver handles for stream 0x528cf90
2021-02-15 16:18:20.375365: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49]
Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-15 16:18:21.854945: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49]
Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-02-15 16:18:21.934489: F tensorflow/core/util/cuda_solvers.cc:120]
Check failed: cublasCreate(&cublas_handle) == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS Failed to create cuBlas instance.
```

The Python interpreter crashes. The CUDA and cuBLAS libraries are successfully opened, so I'm not sure what's causing the error.

The crash also happens with the `tensorflow/tensorflow:devel-gpu` image. When I try an earlier TensorFlow version (2.3), I do not get the error. However, I need to use >=2.4 because that's required by `tensorflow_probability`.

I'm on Pop! OS (Ubuntu 20.10), using a GTX 1650.

---

Edit: Installing tf-nightly natively on the host system doesn't produce the error; `tf.linalg.inv(tf.eye(10))` works fine. This does not solve the problem with the docker image (nightly image still produces the error), but I have a working GPU tensorflow environment for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was solved by allowing memory growth on the GPU:

```
gpu = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device=gpu[0], enable=True)
```